# Some default objects of core data entities

Tags: core-data, entity, default

Here I have some entities in core data, for example, "Account",

and I wish that, when user enter my app for the first time, there is some thing in Account,

to make it more clear, maybe I should say I want to give some default managed-objects for an entity so that they will be there when the app is just installed.

How can I achieve this?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have a similar requirement for an app I'm working on. I am using a sqlite persistence store for my data, so I basically want to pre-populate that table with the data for my default entities.

To do this, I have created a separate project in my Xcode workspace that shares the same data model with my app. In this separate project I write the code I need to insert entities into the table, and to store the file in a well-known place on my Mac.

Then, I copy the sqlite file that my initializer app has created into the resources directory for my "real" app. As part of the startup for that app, I wrote a small bit of code that copies the default DB from the resources to my app's documents folder if a copy doesn't already exist there.

The end result is this: I can run my initializer app to populate the default data as I need to. I then copy the file into my real app, so when the app is first run there is a default copy of that DB ready to go.

Comment: Thanks! I got it. But why don't you just write the code for inserting directly in you "real" app, then you don

Comment: You can of course write the code to pre-populate your DB right within your app if it makes sense for you. In my case, the pre-population is not a trivial task. I need to use an administrative UI I've created, access data from a variety of web services where I am only allowed to pull certain amounts of data per hour, etc. Putting the pre-population code directly in the real app would deny me the control I desire over how that data gets populated.